# Combine multiple Kotlin flows with synchronous

Tags: kotlin, repository, kotlin-flow

I want to make 3 API calls. But 2 API calls must be asynchronous and the last one must be wait this results. And I want to write this in usecase so there is no viewmodelscope. I tried to write with zip but it can only create 2 API calls.

```
class UseCase @Inject constructor(private val repository: Repository) :
        UseCase<Unit, Triple<String, String, String>> {
        override fun invoke(input: Unit): Flow<Triple<String, String, String>> {
            return combine(
                repository.getFirst(),
                repository.getSecond(),
                repository.getThird()
            ) { first, second, third ->
                Triple(first, second, third)
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any different flow method to create synchronous and async together? Or any suggestion?

Comment: Is there are reason why you can't have a use case with a suspend function?

Comment: I agree, separate getFirst, Second, and Third into their own useCases. Then have a useCase combine them any way you want.